# tkinter wait_variable doesn't callback to intvar changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to "advanced programming" and GUIs so this problem is most definetly going to be easy.

I have a GUI made with Tkinter and a window that shows, on two Listboxes, the differences between two databases: one is up-to-date, the other isn't. The user is prompted to choose which entry is up-to-date.

[image]

my problem is that, *until the user hasn't clicked* either one of the "accept" buttons, the program should wait for the response. And I can't figure how to do so. Here's some code:

```
class Page_one(object):
    selected_entries = []   

    def update(self, db_entries, sm_entries):
        non_matches = []

        for db_ent in db_entries:
            for sm_ent in sm_entries:
                if db_ent.name_equals(sm_ent):
                    # name_equals() is a function that compares
                    # name, surname and age of the self.entry with the
                    # target entry and returns True when they differ only in age

                    # if they don't match (i.e. name_equals returns True) i'll add
                    # these two entries to a list and will later show them to the user
                    non_matches.append( (db_ent, sm_ent) )
                    break

        for x, y in non_matches:
            # inserts in the 'l-eft' or 'r-ight' listbox the entry
            self.listbox_insert('l', x)
            self.listbox_insert('r', y)

            # here I want the program to wait for user input and
            # set z = x or y depending on user's choice
            z = user_selected_entry()
            self.selected_entries.append(z)
            send_to_final_db(self.selected_entries)
```

I hope the code is clear, I've omitted a lot of GUI definitions and ausiliar functions (like `listbox_insert('l', x)`).

#### EDIT

this is the code I've been using for the Buttons, in short:

```
...
self.root = Tk()
self.flag = IntVar() # variable that should respond to change
self.btn_accept_left = Button(self.root, text="Accept this", command=lambda: self.flag.set(1))
self.btn_accept_right = Button(self.root, text="Accept this", command=lambda: self.flag.set(2))
self.btn_accept_left.grid(row=2, column=0)
self.btn_accept_right.grid(row=2, column=1)

    ... # until we get to the same point

    for x, y in non_matches:
        # inserts in the 'l-eft' or 'r-ight' listbox the entry
        self.listbox_insert('l', x)
        self.listbox_insert('r', y)

        # here I want the program to wait for user input and
        # set z = x or y depending on user's choice
        self.root.wait_variable(self.flag)

        print('Will it ever move?') # <--- NEVER REACHED

        # flag changed, we continue
        z = user_selected_entry()
        self.selected_entries.append(z)
        send_to_final_db(self.selected_entries)
```

I have tried different versions of event binding onto the Buttons, but none worked. The execution never reaches the instruction (after?) `self.root.wait_variable(self.flag)`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment since I am new here,
this is an event task. You wait for an event to happen and bind an action to it.

see
https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php

Comment: that doesn't stop execution, it only binds an event to the button.